# Why jedi-vim automatically works only after a dot?

Tags: jedi-vim

By default jedi-vim is working only after a dot or we have to trigger it manually using Ctrl+Space.

I need automatically autocompletion of variables and all keywords used in python.

I need autocompletion at all the time like lsp instead of only after dot.